# How can I concatanate a string from an int and a char?

Tags: java

For example I want to concatanate `char a ='A'` and `int b = 5` into `string = "A5"`.

`String string = a + b;` doesn't work.

Comment: Make `a` String

Comment: `String string = String.format("%c%d", a, b);`

Comment: @HimBromBeere Though the answer is basically the same, I don't know if that can be considered a duplicate.  That requires knowledge that an `int + char` solution is the same as `char + char` _before_ asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), where you can append any type of primitives :

```
char a ='A';
int b = 5;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(a);
sb.append(b);

String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! that does it

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for me is to precede the String with an empty String.

```
 String str = "" + 'a'  + 10;
```

The conversion goes from left to right so you start out with a String.

If you do it this way,

```
String str = 'a' + 10 + "";
```

you will get a String value of "107" since the numeric addition is done before the conversion to a String.

Answer (score 1):

One way to convert most primitive values to `String` is to utilize the overloaded method in the `String` class `valueOf()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    char a = 'A';
    int b = 5;

    String str = String.valueOf(a) + b; //Can do either of these two lines, will work the same
    String str2 = a + String.valueOf(b);

    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str2);
}
```

You only need to convert one of the values into `String`, because appending them afterward will automatically convert the other into a `String`.

This method will work on both `char`, and `int` in this scenario, but will also work on `long`, `double`, `float` and `boolean` as well.  This is identical to calling `Integer.toString(int i)` or `Character.toString(i)` etc... but it is convenient to be able to use the same overloaded method for each case instead of requiring to call methods from different classes.

Answer (score 0):

To all the answers already given I provide one that explain why "it doesn´t work" as you expect. A string is nothing but an immutable collection of `char`. A `char` itself is nothing but a (signed) integer and thus can implicitely converted to such. Thus when you write `char`+ `int` an integer-operation occurs, in your case `A` + `5` which results in `70`, because ASCII-code for `A` is 65.

Last but not least `String s = 70` surely does not compile, because a number can´t be converted to a string.

So you have to tell the compiler that you do not want an integer-operation, but a string-concatenation, which is by turning one of the operands into a string already:

```
String s = 'A'.toString() + 5
```

or

```
String s = 'A' + 5.toString()
```

Comment: Both examples perform an unnecessary boxing. Not that it matters because the performance impact of string manipulation is often much worse.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Well, in order to get the data from the int, you **have** to box it at some point, so I don´t get how you would go about that. Anyone the core of my answer was the "why", not the "how".

Comment: Note that in Java9+ `String` is backed by a `byte []` instead of a `char []`, though this is largely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Nexevis Good to know. But you´re right, doesn´t change the semantics behind.

Comment: `"" + 5` doesn't box, as doesn't `Integer.toString(5)` or `String.valueOf(5)`.